# Trace is not working in Actionscript 3 Flash CS5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am having an issue with using trace();

For example, at multiple points in my project (and other projects) I had trace statements, which functioned until recently. For some reason now, in the same projects where it worked before, trace no longer displays anything in the Output window.

I have checked and done the following:

1. Verified that the filter for Output is either None or Verbose
2. I'm publish previewing to Flash, not HTML
3. In the publish settings tab, "omit trace actions" is unchecked
4. Verified I have  flash player debugger by double checking with right clicking on flashplayer window, and seeing the option "Debugger".
5. Reset workspace, just in case there was something funky going on.
6. Read 3 other posts in StackOverflow about same issue, tried each one's solution but yet to get it to work.

Does anyone have any ideas? I had added complete code.

```
package  
{
//importing classes
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.Event;
//END importing classes
public class Main extends Sprite
{
    //class level variables
    private const FIELD_W:uint=9;
    private const FIELD_H:uint=9;
    private const NUM_MINES:uint=10;
    private var mineField:Array=new Array();
    private var game_container:Sprite=new Sprite();
    private var tile:tile_movieclip;
    private var timer:Timer=new Timer(1000);
    private var toolbar:toolbar_mc;
    private var gameOver:Boolean=false;
    private var firstClick:Boolean=true;
    private var remainingTiles:uint=FIELD_W*FIELD_H;
    private var minesLeft:uint=NUM_MINES;
    private var screenFrame:Screens; 
    //END class level variables

    public function Main() 
    {

        //Mine Field Creation
        for (var i:uint=0; i<FIELD_H; i++)
        {
            mineField[i]=new Array();
            for (var j:uint=0; j<FIELD_W; j++)
            {
                mineField[i].push(0);
            }

        }
        trace("My dangerous mine field: "+mineField);
                //END Mine Field Creation

        addChild(game_container);

        for (i=0; i<FIELD_H; i++) 
        {
            for (j=0; j<FIELD_W; j++) 
            {
            tile = new tile_movieclip();
            game_container.addChild(tile);
            tile.gotoAndStop(1);
            tile.nrow=i;
            tile.ncol=j;
            tile.buttonMode=true;
            tile.x=tile.width*j;
            tile.y=tile.height*i;
            tile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onTileClicked);
            }
        }
        // end of tile creation
        //time amangement and game over
        toolbar = new toolbar_mc();
        addChild(toolbar);
        //var s_height:uint= stage.height;
        toolbar.y=725;
        timer.start();
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTick);
        //end of time management and game over

    }//END Main function
    private function onTick(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
        toolbar.message_text.text="Elapsed time: "+timer.currentCount+"s";
        //trace("Elapsed time: "+timer.currentCount);
    }
    private function tileValue(row,col:uint):int
    {
        if (mineField[row]==undefined || mineField[row][col]==undefined)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return mineField[row][col];
        }
    }
    private function onTileClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (!gameOver && remainingTiles > 0)
        {

            var clicked_tile:tile_movieclip=e.currentTarget as tile_movieclip;
            clicked_tile.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onTileClicked);
            clicked_tile.buttonMode=false;
            var clickedRow:uint=clicked_tile.nrow;
            var clickedCol:uint=clicked_tile.ncol;
            var clickedValue:uint=mineField[clickedRow][clickedCol];
            if (firstClick)
            {
                firstClick=false;
                //placing mines
                var placedMines:uint=0;
                var randomRow,randomCol:uint;
                while (placedMines<NUM_MINES)
                {
                    randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random()*FIELD_H);
                    randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random()*FIELD_W);
                    if (mineField[randomRow][randomCol] ==0)
                    {
                        if (randomRow!=clickedRow||randomCol!=clickedCol) 
                        {
                            mineField[randomRow][randomCol] = 9;
                            placedMines++;
                        }
                    }
                }//END placing Mines
                // placing digits
                for (var i:uint=0; i<FIELD_H; i++) 
                {
                for (var j:uint=0; j<FIELD_W; j++) 
                {
                    if (mineField[i][j]==9) 
                    {
                        for (var ii:int =-1; ii<=1; ii++) 
                        {
                            for (var jj:int =-1; jj<=1; jj++) 
                            {
                                if (ii!=0||jj!=0) 
                                {
                                    if (tileValue(i+ii,j+jj)!=9&&tileValue(i+ii,j+jj)!=-1) 
                                    {
                                        mineField[i+ii][j+jj]++;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
                var debugString:String;
                trace("My complete and formatted mine field: ");
                for (i=0; i<FIELD_H; i++) 
                {
                    debugString="";
                    for (j=0; j<FIELD_W; j++) 
                    {
                    debugString+=mineField[i][j]+" ";
                    }
                    trace(debugString);
                }
                // end of placing digits

                // tile creation
                    }
                    if (e.shiftKey)
                    {
                        clicked_tile.gotoAndStop(5-clicked_tile.currentFrame);
                        remainingTiles--;
                        if (remainingTiles ==0)
                            {
                                timer.stop();
                                //Create a for loop involving string for number that appears on tiles
                                toolbar.message_text.text="WinBomb";
                                screenFrame = new Screens();
                                game_container.addChild(screenFrame);
                                screenFrame.gotoAndStop("win");
                            }                               
                        if (clickedValue ==9)
                        {
                            minesLeft--;
                            if (minesLeft==0)
                                {
                                    timer.stop();
                                    //Create a for loop involving string for number that appears on tiles
                                    toolbar.message_text.text="Mine Free!!";
                                    removeChild(toolbar);
                                    screenFrame = new Screens();
                                    game_container.addChild(screenFrame);
                                    screenFrame.gotoAndStop("win");
                                }                               
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //empty tile
                        if (clickedValue == 0)
                        {
                            floodFill(clickedRow,clickedCol);
                        }//END empty Tile
                        // numbered tile
                        if (clickedValue>0&&clickedValue<9) 
                        {
                            clicked_tile.gotoAndStop(2);
                            clicked_tile.tile_text.text=clickedValue.toString();
                            remainingTiles--;
                            if (remainingTiles ==0)
                            {
                                toolbar.message_text.text="Mine Free!!";
                                removeChild(toolbar);
                                screenFrame = new Screens();
                                game_container.addChild(screenFrame);
                                screenFrame.gotoAndStop("win");
                            }
                        }// end of numbered tile
                        // mine
                        if (clickedValue==9) 
                        {
                            clicked_tile.gotoAndStop(3);
                            timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTick);
                            removeChild(toolbar);
                            screenFrame = new Screens();
                            game_container.addChild(screenFrame);
                            screenFrame.gotoAndStop("lose");
                            /*timer=new Timer(5000);
                            timer.start();
                            trace("Timer to End: "+timer.currentCount);
                            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, loseScreen);                              screenFrame = new Screens();
                            */
                        }// end of mine
                    }
                }
        else if (remainingTiles == 0)
        {
            timer.stop();
            toolbar.message_text.text="Mine Free!!";
            removeChild(toolbar);
            screenFrame = new Screens();
            game_container.addChild(screenFrame);
            screenFrame.gotoAndStop("win");
        }

    }//END onTileClicked function
    private function floodFill(row,col:uint):void 
    {
        var emptyTile:tile_movieclip;
        emptyTile=game_container.getChildAt(row*FIELD_W+col) as tile_movieclip;
        if (emptyTile.currentFrame==1) 
        {
            emptyTile.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onTileClicked);
            emptyTile.buttonMode=false;
            emptyTile.gotoAndStop(2);

            if (mineField[row][col]>0) 
            {
                emptyTile.tile_text.text=mineField[row][col].toString();
                remainingTiles--;
            } 
            else 
            {
                emptyTile.gotoAndStop(5);
                remainingTiles--;

            }
            if (mineField[row][col]==0) 
            {
                for (var ii:int =-1; ii<=1; ii++)
                {
                    for (var jj:int =-1; jj<=1; jj++) 
                    {
                        if (ii!=0||jj!=0) 
                        {
                            if (tileValue(row+ii,col+jj)!=9) 
                            {
                                if (tileValue(row+ii,col+jj)!=-1) 
                                {
                                    floodFill(row+ii,col+jj);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }//END floodFill
/*  private function loseScreen(e:TimerEvent)
    {
        timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, loseScreen);
        game_container.addChild(screenFrame);
        screenFrame.gotoAndStop("lose");
    }*/
}//END Main CLass

}//END package
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the lines where you trace are being reached?

Comment: Code? Simplified, if possible?

Comment: Adding code now, this used to show trace in Output, now it does not and the code has not been changed. @Craig

Comment: Absolutely sure its reached @LDMS

Comment: Is there any chance you could post up your variable instantiations in addition to just your `main` function? I'm trying to debug your code but there is so much missing code that even if I recreated placeholder code for the custom classes I can't guarantee that my debugging will accurately reproduce your issue and allow me to help you fix it. For example, you have `mineField[i] = new Array();` specified in your code, but you do not show anywhere in the posted code where the `mineField` array is instantiated.

Comment: Could you please try putting a single `trace("GOT HERE!");` statement as the first line in your `Main` function call. Does that trace to the output panel?  Also, please double check that there are 0 compiler errors when you publish your code.

Comment: @SlyRaskal, I have added the variables and also the got here trace. The trace still does not appear.

Comment: Have you tried creating a brand new .fla file and trying a trace statement with that.  If that works, then there may be a problem with your project, if that doesn't work, then you have a problem with your Flash Installation or something else on your computer.

Comment: I have tried a new fla with just the trace line, and nothing still. I may have to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the top part of your code, here's a slight re-arrangement. In this experiment I've taken the liberty of initializing your '_FIELD' variables.  Try it. Does this solve your problem?

```
var mineField:Array = new Array;        
var FIELD_H:int = 10;
var FIELD_W:int = 20;

for (var i:uint=0; i<FIELD_H; i++)
{
    mineField[i]=new Array();
    for (var j:uint=0; j<FIELD_W; j++)
    {
        mineField[i].push(0);
    }

}

trace(mineField);
```

Comment: It does not, still no trace output.

Comment: Interesting.  Can you trace ANYTHING in another .fla file? Try setting up a new .fla, without external code, and just write: trace ("I can read this") into the actionscript (F9) panel. If no trace then look at publish settings. Under 'ADVANCED' make sure that 'Omit trace statements' is not checked.  If problem persists send back to me the minimnum bit of code that produces your problem.

Comment: I can't trace anything in any FLA. I created a new fla, and in the actions tab i put trace("hi"); and still nothing.

Comment: Did you follow my suggestion about the publish settings?   What are your machine specs?

Comment: I have reconfirmed the publish setting, but as stated in my original post, I had already checked that.

Comment: Have you tried testing from the 'Debug' menu option? (Debug > Debug Movie > In Flash Professional)

Comment: I have just tried, but still does not show trace. @ Craig

Comment: Well, you've got me. Something's buggy somewhere. At this point I'd uninstall and re-install Flash. Maybe time for an upgrade if you're really on 5.0, eh?

Answer (score 0):

**First**

Your `Main Class` isn't correctly written. If it's imported, your compiler should output the following `error message`:

> 1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.

Because the general form of a Class is:

```
package myPackage
{
    class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

**On the other hand**

Specifically, this `error message` doesn't occur because you haven't probably imported your `Main class`:

File > ActionScript Settings > Document Class : `Main`

Comment: I do not get that, the program works without error or warning. I have now put ALL the code so that you can compile it.

Comment: You haven't imported your class. Does your `Main` class appears on your `ActionScript Settings panel`? Like i said you, if this class was imported, your compiler should output an error message, because your class is not correctly written (into a package).

Comment: @Mark Rivinius - If you edit your question (adding package after my remark) without answering me about your ActionScript Panel, it will be difficult to resolve your problem!

Comment: Yes, Main does appear in the Document Class box in the Advance ActionScript 3.0 Settings @helloflash